# URLs absolutas con PHP

Tags: php, pretty-urls

Explico mi problema, es sencillo, lo tengo solucionado, pero solamente de manera local, no me sirve lo que hice si yo uso esto en un servidor normal.

Yo modifique mi **.htaccess** para las URLs amigables, el tema es que tengo problemas con las rutas de los archivos (**css**, **imagenes**, **js**, etc).

Porque por ejemplo, mi ruta es:

> localhost/proyecto/user/pepito/

Entonces, cuando yo enlazo mi CSS o imágenes, normalmente, me da esto:

[image: captura]

Osea, no me esta tomando la ruta del archivo.

Yo tengo este código PHP en un archivo, para usarlo poder tener la URL absoluta y no tener problemas (Ya de paso, se los comparto):

```
$s = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$a = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 3);
$completeURL = "http://".$s."/".$a[1];
```

De esta forma, estaría guardando en la variable **completeUrl**:

> http://**localhost**/proyecto

Entonces, cuando voy a poner una imagen, pondría:

```
<img src="<?php echo $completeURL; ?>/images/img.png" alt="">
```

Entonces, si funciona, pero esto en el servidor normal no me sirve, porque me imprime:

> http://example.com/index.php

Entonces, yo lo que busco, en una manera de poder imprimir siempre toda la ruta, sin necesidad de tener que cambiar todo mi códigos para que funcione en el servidor. Tengo demasiadas rutas puestas de la forma que ya mostre, pero si por ejemplo, yo tengo una imagen y uso:

```
<img src="<?php echo $completeURL; ?>/images/img.png" alt="">
```

Esto me imprimiría:

> http://example.com/index.php/images/img.png

No tendría sentido. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Porque no [defines constantes](http://php.net/manual/es/function.define.php)? Lo tienes todo en un lugar y listo

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en esto, no tengo idea de como sería eso @aldanux

Comment: Acabo de leer que con la etiqueta BASE de HTML, se soluciona

Comment: Pero con `<base>` puedes definir solo 1... con define la que quieras ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo y tu no estabas tan lejos.

Te dejo aquí una variante con [define](http://php.net/manual/es/function.define.php):

Puedes crear un archivo, por ejemplo: `define.php` y en esa creamos los defines constante:

```
<?php
    define('URL_WEBSITE_COM', 'http://example.com');

    // y otra especialmente para imágenes por ejemplo:
    define('URL_IMAGE', 'http://example.com/images/');
```

luego incluyes ese fichero a tus archivos necesarios y lo usas de esta manera:

```
<img src="<?php echo URL_IMAGE; ?>img.png" alt="">
```

o

```
<a href="<?php echo URL_WEBSITE_COM; ?>/Foo">Bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno miren apenas yo resolvi esto y es que xampp es un simulador de servidor por tanto entrar como (< src="c:/root/proyecto" >) no sirve con localhost si pero antecediendo a cualquier contenido dentro de xampp ya sea en la raiz del proyecto o lo que sea pero con la notacion http://localhost/root/proyecto asi la url puede sr absoluta y la puedes llamar desde cualquier php o html desde dentro de xampp, ami me hizo sufrir bastante ignorar eso pero ahora les comparto para enriquecer sus proyectos saludos