# Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy migrando un proyecto a la versión más reciente de php. Para hacerlo más dinámico estoy utilizando una librería que me pareció cómoda a lo que requiere el proyecto, esta librería me ayuda a hacer las rutas de mi proyecto.
https://github.com/izniburak/php-router

Para funcionar requiero poner lo siguiente en el htaccess y hasta ahí no tengo problema:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

El inconveniente es que hay una series de URL's que llevan parámetros GET's y debo convertirlas a URL amigables. Por ejemplo:

http://localhost/proyecto.com/temas?search&ciudad=1

http://localhost/proyecto.com/temas/ciudad1

Estoy intentando hacer lo que tenía en el proyecto anterior, pero no me funciona:

```
RewriteRule ^temas/ciudad1 temas?search&ciudad=1 [L]
```

Honestamente no entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento de htaccess y no creí al final tener tanto inconveniente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recientemente he visto varias preguntas relacionadas con el tema de las direcciones amigables. Y, las respuestas, cuando las han habido no me satisfacen. Decidí, aprovechar esta pregunta y tratar de responder a todas como conjunto. Eso hace que me extienda un poco más de lo necesario.

Cuando se plantea la posibilidad de **hacer uso de direcciones amigables** se debe tener presente que se piensa **usar aliases** que van a enmascarar las **direcciones reales** de acceso a los archivos de recursos. Particularmente, se van a enmascarar los llamados a los archivos de código que sirven las respuestas.
Más aún, **los llamados deben ser canalizados** a través de un archivo "puerta de entrada" puesto que de otra forma el archivo **.htaccess** tendría que convertirse en una miniaplicación enrutadora imposible de mantener.

Esto plantea problemas adicionales:

1. ¿Como escribir un archivo .htaccess **liviano** que dirija sin error a la puerta de entrada?
2. ¿Cómo resolver el enrutamiento para las posibles solicitudes de páginas? y
3. ¿Cómo enlazar internamente las direcciones relativas? porque las direcciones amigables **mueven con cierta arbitrariedad** los niveles de profundidad en la estructura de directorios **percibida por los navegadores**. (Ej: si la puerta es el archivo index.php, y el llamado es a `suDominio/seccion/subseccion/grupo/descriptor_de_id la página` **está a 4 niveles de profundidad** y no el primer nivel que es dónde se encuentra index. Y, análogamente, para otras páginas los niveles serán otros.)

### 1. El asunto del .htaccess

Se deben tener en cuenta dos escenarios: Servidores locales, con o sin aliases para la carpeta pública, en los que típicamente el directorio publico será algo como **tuSutioLocal** y los servicios de hosting donde el directorio público va a ser apuntado por **/**
En ambos casos nos planteamos las siguientes condiciones:

1. Todo el aplicativo php va a estar fuera del directorio público, quizás a su mismo nivel (lo típico en servicios de hosting) o en una carpeta como /home/user/documentos/aplicativo/ llamaré **<path_al_aplicativo>** a su dirección y **<directorio_publico>** al directorio público.
2. Dentro del directorio público estarán los archivos de recursos que típicamente son servidos con las páginas así:

- **<directorio_publico>/css** hojas de estilo y sus imágenes asociadas (fondos etc).
- **<directorio_publico>/js** archivos de código javascript.
- **<directorio_publico>/img** imágenes subidas vía upload por usuarios (avatares, etc) e imágenes de uso general sin referencias en las hojas de estilo.
- **<directorio_publico>/files** Archivos de usuarios y que van a ser ofrecidos para descarga.

3. **Ninguna dirección de acceso al sitio** apuntará a algún archivo existente en la estructura del directorio público (salvo ciertos index.html o index.php que se explican más abajo). De modo que sólo los archivos de recursos públicos (porque son servidos con las páginas o desde ellas) podrán ser apuntados desde fuera.
4. Todas las peticiones de **direcciones de recursos inexistentes** serán redirigidas al archivo **index.php** que será el único acompañante de **.htaccess** en el directorio público.

#### Con esto en mente veamos un ejemplo de archivo .htaccess

**Este bloque responde explícitamente a la pregunta planteada por el OP.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tuSutioLocal  #Si está en un servidor local
#RewriteBase / # Descomente está línea si está en un servicio de hosting
               # y comente la línea para servidor local
# La siguiente regla indica al servidor Apache que si el archivo solicitado
# existe debe servirlo normalmente.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
# La regla siguiente toma todas las solicitudes a recursos inexistentes 
# en particular las direcciones amigables y las redirige a index.php
# ello asegura que sea la única puerta de entrada a la aplicación.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Con este modelo de escritura se ha dejado la puerta abierta a revisiones de los directorios interiores. Necesitamos ponerle un pequeño cerrojo:

#### Bloqueo de la revisión de los directorios bajo el directorio público

Se pueden fijar reglas adicionales, anidar en ellos otros .htaccess, etc. Voy a proponer una solución sencilla (pañito de agua tibia) En todos los directorios anidados bajo **<directorio_publico>** se escribe un index.html bloqueador que muestre una leyenda negando el acceso. p.ej:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Página no encontrada</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center><!-- esta etiqueta está desaconsejada, pero funciona y no quiero enlazar estilos -->
    <h3>Página no encontrada</h3>
    <p>No se encontró un controlador que pueda resolver la dirección solicitada.</p>
    <!-- cualquier cuento sirve al propósito de decir: No me da la gana de mostrarle el directorio. Pero, este suena decente. -->
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

### 2. Solución al asunto del enrutamiento al usar direcciones amigables

Como se dijo arriba ninguna dirección amigable va a corresponder a algo que exista dentro de la estructura del directorio público. De modo que el archivo **index.php** ha de ofrecer un mecanismo para interpretarlas y devolver la respuesta. Para hacerlo hay muchos enfoques posibles, y el aparentemente más barato sería poner un bloque

```
<?php
$direccion = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($direccion){ 
    case 'direcion_uno': 
        //codigo adecuado para responder a direccion_uno
        break;
    case 'otra_direccion':
        //codigo correspondiente 
        break;
    default:
        //código para respuesta por defecto (bienvenida, etc)
}
// el archivo va sin etiqueta de cierre en muchos casos genera problemas
```

pero, con seguridad acabaría por volverse inmanejable.
En consecuencia es necesario proponerse una solución que cuente con un mecanismo de registro e interpretación de rutas y asigne adecuadamente las tareas.
Una solución más sensata adoptaría una forma como la siguiente:

```
<?php
// <directorio_publico>/index.php
// 1. Invoca la carga de las bibliotecas de código compartido requeridas por
// los módulos de la aplicación a ejecutar.
include '<path_al_aplicativo>/cargador_de_codigo.php';
// 2. Ejecuta la aplicación
Aplicacion::ejecutar();
// el archivo que contiene a la clase Aplicacion fue cargado en paso anterior
// allí serán resueltas las rutas y se establecerá el camino a seguir.
```

#### Un prototipo MVC para tratar las rutas amigables

El paradigma Modelo Vista Controlador [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) está de moda. Y, en varias de las preguntas relacionadas con el uso de direcciones amigables quienes las plantean señalan estar tratando con él.
Para resolver el asunto debe existir, en algún sitio un archivo (o una tabla en la BD) en el que se registren **semirrutas** y controladores y eventualmente vistas, a no ser que se defina un protocolo que permita identificar las vistas asociadas con las **semirrutas**. Hablo de **semirrutas** porque para que las rutas amigables tengan sentido conviene que tengan una parte significativa que las caracterice (**semirruta**) y una cola de parámetros opcionales. Algo como:
ruta = `seccion/subseccion/grupo/identificador[/param1[/param2[/...]]]`
dónde seccion/subseccion/grupo/identificador es una semirruta y
[/param1[/param2[/...]]] es una cola de parámetros opcionales y la cantidad de niveles en las semirrutas es variable.

**Archivo de registro de rutas**

```
<?php
// **<path_al_aplicativo>/rutas_config.php**
// Devuelve un array de rutas y controladores
return [
    'semirruta1' => [
        controlador => ruta1Controlador,
        metodo => procesadorDeRuta1,
        path => '' | 'path al archivo de código bajo <path_al_aplicativo>',
    ],
    // siguen más declaraciones
];
```

**Mecanismo de resolución de rutas**
En esencia se trata de identificar unívocamente la ruta solicitada. Puede definirse un método o una clase enrutadora si se desea que realice tareas complementarias (como validar permisos de acceso, etc.). Para no extender mucho ilustraré únicamente el mecanismo de identificación de la ruta mediante una función:

```
<?php
// mecanismo enrutador
function resolverRutaInvocada(){
    $params = []; // array para recoger la cola de parámetros
    $llamado = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //ojo en instalaciones locales 
                                        //puede contener el nombre del sitio
    // se va a recorrer la ruta recortandola (puede haber otros modos de iterar 
    // más eficientes pero este es muy intuitivo y facilita comprender)
    // De modo que se va a encontrar la ruta registrada más larga que caza
    // con la solicitud y la cola excedente se interpretará como parametros
    $partes = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $llamado);
    $i = count($partes);
    $controlador = '';
    $rutas = include '<path_al_aplicativo>/rutas_config.php';
    while($controlador == ''){
        if(isset($rutas[$llamado]){
            // si la ruta fue registrada se preparan las variables para usarla
            $controlador = $rutas[$llamado]['controlador'];
            $metodo = $rutas[$llamado]['metodo'];
            $path  = $rutas[$llamado]['path'];
            if(($path) && file_exists('<path_al_aplicativo>/'.$path){
                // carga el archivo del controlador si no se hizo antes
                include_once '<path_al_aplicativo>/'.$path;
            }
        }elseif($i == 0){
            // si se recorrieron todos los pedazos se delega en controlador
            // por defecto allí se decide si va a Ruta no existe err 404 o si
            // muestra la bienvenida
            $controlador = 'controladorPorDefecto';
            $metodo = 'index';
        }else{
            // prepara la siguiente iteración
            $i--;
            $param = array_pop($partes); // recorta el último segmento
            array_unshift($params, $param); // y lo pasa a parámetros
            // prepara la semirruta para la iteración
            $llamado = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $partes);
        }
    }
    // Al terminar el loop se tienen los datos deseados
    // Basta cargar el controlador pasandole los parámetros
    $herramienta = new $controlador($params);
    $vista = $herramienta->$metodo();
    return $vista;
}
```

Ahora hay que hacer algo con la vista: **Servirla** ese tema es al gusto...

### 3. El asunto del acceso a los recursos desde las páginas

Como no es viable saber de antemano el nivel de profundidad al que estarán todas las páginas; y si por casualidad se definen bloques que puedan ser compartidos por muchas rutas que no siempre van a estar al mismo nivel. Está totalmente desaconsejado el uso de rutas relativas para asociar recursos. Se debe usar rutas absolutas. En su respuesta a la pregunta [URLs absolutas con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27923/91033) [@Black Sheep](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/black-sheep) ilustra y comenta el mecanismo bastante bien. De modo que carece de sentido que yo lo haga.