# Remover parametros e index de URLs antiguas (HTACCESS)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección, mod-rewrite, querystring

Tengo cientos de URLS antiguas en este formato indexadas en Google.

```
http://example/folder/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867:venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano&catid=14:14&Itemid=574

http://example/folder/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60216:aeromexico-y-japan-airlines-tienen-codigo-compartido&catid=93:mundo&Itemid=45
```

Necesito que se redirijan a la web con el nuevo formato de URLs

```
https://example/folder/venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano

https://example/folder/aeromexico-y-japan-airlines-tienen-codigo-compartido
```

Es decir, eliminar todos los parametros, el index.php y el ":".

**¿Como podría armar el código en el htaccess?**

**UPDATE 1:**

Para ser más directos. De las URLs que tienen este formato

```
http://example/folder/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867:venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano&catid=14:14&Itemid=574
```

Necesito eliminar estas cadenas:

index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867:
&catid=14:14&Itemid=574

Quedando así:

```
https://example/folder/venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Este es mi htaccess en la raiz con el código proporcionado por @jachguate

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com\.pe [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com.pe/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=([0-9]+):([0-9a-z\-]+)&catid=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/index\.php /folder/%2? [R=302,L]
```

He probado cargando pero aun no funciona. Me devuelve la URL así:

```
https://example/folder/?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867%3Avenezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano&catid=14%3A14&Itemid=574
```

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: No me queda claro si el contenido de las urls antiguas ya no existe, o el contenido de las nuevas urls es el mismo que en las antiguas.

Comment: Hola. Por lo que puedo percibir te debe servir algo que acepte cualquier dirección que tenga la forma `http(s)://tusitio/foler1/folder2/.../folderN` con o sin slash final y (s) = con o sin s. Hace algunos días escribí una respuesta que te puede servir: [A - Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033) En ella se presenta un mecanismo que puede servir para lo que necesitas.

Comment: Adicionalmente. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Aprovecha para hacer el [tour] y consulta [ask] eso ayudará a que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas y puedas obtener ayuda oportuna. Y, no olvides que tus problemas no son exclusivamente tuyos, muchos otros los han (hemos) tenido y cabe esperar que haya consultas con propósitos similares. **Toma siempre un tiempo para buscar lo que se ha preguntado/respondido al respecto**.

Comment: @Elboy El contenido es el mismo. Se ha realizado un cambio de CMS. De joomla a wordpress que ha involucrado el nuevo formato de URLs

Comment: Gracias @quevedo por tu respuesta. 

Para ser más directos. De las URLs que tienen este formato

http://example/folder/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867:venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano&catid=14:14&Itemid=574


Necesito eliminar estas cadenas:

index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44867:
&catid=14:14&Itemid=574

Quedando así:
https://example/folder/venezuela-conviasa-ofrecera-50-destinos-nacionales-e-internacionales-este-ano

Answer (score 0):

Esto debiera hacer el trabajo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=([0-9]+):([0-9a-z\-]+)&catid=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/index\.php /folder/%2? [R=301,L]
```

En `RewriteCond` evalúo que incluya los parámetros de interés, separando en un grupo particular la expresión que nos interesa mantener como parte del resultado. He incluido en este grupo las letras del abecedario en inglés, los números y el guión, que es lo que puedo observar en el ejemplo que se da.

Finalmente, en el `RewriteRule` evalúo que se trate del script `/folder/index.php`, hago la redirección utilizando el grupo preparado en el paso anterior y detengo la evaluación de más expresiones, si las hubiera.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jachguate voy a probarlo. Una consulta, tengo codigo en el htaccess generado por wordpress. Donde debería poner este código que has publicado?

Comment: Diría que al inicio, justo después de encender el mod_rewrite, a manera que sea lo primero que se evalúe, y si hay coincidencia con el CMS anterior, ya no se evalúe nada de lo del CMS nuevo.

Comment: Hola @jachguate! he probado agregando el código y no redirige (inicialmente probe con un 302). Actualmente tengo este código generado (NOTICIERO es la carpeta que puse como FOLDER en el ejemplo.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteBase /noticiero/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /noticiero/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: El orden de las condiciones es importante. Mi respuesta la puedes probar en https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ contra la URL que has puesto de ejemplo. Por otro lado, el código en comentarios queda realmente difícil de leer.

Comment: Hola nuevamente @jachguate! He actualizado mi publicación con el código htaccess que tengo en la raiz del sitio web. Agregué el código que me brindaste y no resuelve la url como en htaccess.madewithlove.be