# url amigables con .htaccess no funciona

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Buenas noches estoy haciendo que mis url sean amigables actualmente asi esta mi .htaccess

```
#URL LIMPIA
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cursos/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ cursos.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^curso/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ curso.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

pero no esta funcionando, solo funciona de la manera tradicional con el caracter "?"

[image: htaccess malo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque no esta encontrando mi variable?. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Hiroshy. Hace algunos días respondí a una pregunta similar a la tuya: [Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033). Me parece que allí puedes encontrar una solución funcional. Cuando tengas preguntas **consulta antes usando el buscador** siempre es posible que alguien haya hecho preguntas similares.

Comment: Te paso este lonk que quiza te ayude.
https://www.galisteocantero.com/activar-modulo-mod_rewrite-de-apache-en-linux-y-windows/
Quiza no este activo el mod_rewrite

Comment: La reescritura la está realizando bien, fijate que está accediendo a cursos.php, como se  muestra en tu última imagen. El problema está en el código de PHP, precisamente en la línea 15, tal cual te lo dice en el error

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias el error lo tenia con las expresiones regulares.Por lo que lo solucione de la siguiente forma.

ANTES

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cursos/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ cursos.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^curso/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ curso.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

AHORA

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cursos/(*)$ cursos.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^curso/(*)$ curso.php?slug=$1 [L]
```