# Puedo editar la URL de mi sitio web php con .htaccess?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¿Es posible con .htaccess eliminar el ID de la URL y simplemente mostrar un texto?

Actualmente tengo esta URL:

```
http://localhost/productos/producto.php?id=3
```

y me gustaria lograr que se vea de la siguiente manera por ejemplo:

```
http://localhost/productos/toyota
```

CODIGO:

```
<a href="productos/producto.php?id=<?php echo $producto['id']?>">
```

BASE DE DATOS:

[image: IMAGEN]

He estado investigando por varios lugares y explican que esto se edita usando .htaccess pero la verdad no entiendo mucho sobre el tema y necesito ayuda. ¿Por favor me podrian explicar?.

Comment: Hola. Hace algún tiempo respondí a una pregunta y allí explico como se logra lo que buscas. Si lo lees con cuidado tienes la solución. [configurar .htaccess para tener direcciones amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033)

Comment: En la primera url hace eso porque estas enviando una "variable" (para que te identifique que es Toyota) "via $_REQUEST". Para solucionar eso, la debes enviar via $_POST. También puedes hacer tu diseño y código para que no cambies de pagina (URL) y cambiar el href=toyota. En esto que preguntas no entiendo que tiene que ver el htaccess, pero puedes esperar mas respuestas, tal vez si se pueda de la forma que comentas.