# Error 500 con htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

quiero hacer una url amigable y tengo error 500 y no puedo solucionarlo

Este es mi archivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEmgine On

RewriteBase /nube/proyectos/csm/panel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

y este es mi `index.php`

```
<?php
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : "home"; // me lleva a la página home
$url = explode("/", rtrim($url, "/"));

// var_dump($url);

require_once "paginas/".$url[0].".php";
?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola. Por favor revisa esta respuesta a la pregunta [R - Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033) creo que tiene la solución que buscas. En cierto setido tu pregunta puede ser duplicado de aquella.

Comment: Adicional `RewriteEmgine On` debiera estar escrito como `RewriteEngine On` con **n** en lugar de **m**. De ahí puede venir el error, pues al no habilitar la reescritura no hay reglas y la dirección amigable no actúa.